# Controlling the number of spawned futures to create backpressure

Tags: asynchronous, rust, future, amazon-kinesis

I am using a [futures-rs powered version of the Rusoto AWS Kinesis library](https://github.com/srijs/rusoto-async). I need to spawn a deep pipeline of AWS Kinesis requests to achieve high-throughput because Kinesis has a limit of 500 records per HTTP request. Combined with the 50ms latency of sending a request, I need to start generating many concurrent requests. I am looking to create somewhere on the order of 100 in-flight requests.

The Rusoto `put_records` function signature looks like this:

```
fn put_records(
    &self,
    input: &PutRecordsInput,
) -> RusotoFuture<PutRecordsOutput, PutRecordsError>
```

The `RusotoFuture` is a wrapper defined like this:

```
/// Future that is returned from all rusoto service APIs.
pub struct RusotoFuture<T, E> {
    inner: Box<Future<Item = T, Error = E> + 'static>,
}
```

The inner `Future` is wrapped but the `RusutoFuture` still implements `Future::poll()`, so I believe it is compatible with the `futures-rs`  ecosystem. The `RusotoFuture` provides a synchronization call:

```
impl<T, E> RusotoFuture<T, E> {
    /// Blocks the current thread until the future has resolved.
    ///
    /// This is meant to provide a simple way for non-async consumers
    /// to work with rusoto.
    pub fn sync(self) -> Result<T, E> {
        self.wait()
    }
}
```

I can issue a request and `sync()` it, getting the result from AWS. I would like to create many requests, put them in some kind of queue/list, and gather finished requests. If the request errored I need to reissue the request (this is somewhat normal in Kinesis, especially when hitting limits on your shard throughput). If the request is completed successfully I should issue a request with new data. I could spawn a thread for each request and sync it but that seems inefficient when I have the async IO thread running.

I have tried using [`futures::sync::mpsc::channel`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.17/futures/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html) from my application thread (not running from inside the Tokio reactor) but whenever I clone the `tx` it generates its own buffer, eliminating any kind of backpressure on `send`:

```
fn kinesis_pipeline(client: DefaultKinesisClient, stream_name: String, num_puts: usize, puts_size: usize) {
    use futures::sync::mpsc::{ channel, spawn };
    use futures::{ Sink, Future, Stream };
    use futures::stream::Sender;
    use rusoto_core::reactor::DEFAULT_REACTOR;

    let client = Arc::new(KinesisClient::simple(Region::UsWest2));
    let data = FauxData::new(); // a data generator for testing

    let (mut tx, mut rx) = channel(1);

    for rec in data {
        tx.clone().send(rec);
    }
}
```

Without the clone, I have the error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `tx`
   --> src/main.rs:150:9
    |
150 |         tx.send(rec);
    |         ^^ value moved here in previous iteration of loop
    |
    = note: move occurs because `tx` has type `futures::sync::mpsc::Sender<rusoto_kinesis::PutRecordsRequestEntry>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I have also look at [`futures::mpsc::sync::spawn`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.17/futures/sync/mpsc/fn.spawn.html) based on recommendations but it takes owner ship of the `rx` (as a `Stream`) and does not solve my problem with the `Copy` of `tx` causing unbounded behavior.

I'm hoping if I can get the `channel`/`spawn` usage working, I will have a system which takes `RusotoFuture`s, waits for them to complete, and then provides me an easy way to grab completion results from my application thread.

Comment: Did you have a look at [`Stream::buffered`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.17/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.buffered) yet? Combine it with a (possibly `unsync`) channel, and maybe it does what you need.  You'll probably need to share the handle to the `mpsc::Sender` through (`Rc<RefCell<..>>` or `Arc<Mutex<..>>`) anyway.

Comment: @Stefan why do you need the `Rc` / `Arc`? Shouldn't you be able to clone the `Sender`?

Comment: @Shepmaster Right, it already does this itself, `clone` should be fine. I guess "whenever I `clone` the tx it generates its own buffer" confused me (that shouldn't be true, the buffer should get shared).

Comment: Also `channel(1)` is a really small buffer considering you're building cyclic dependencies: if a request can trigger a new request, but has to wait to push a new one until it finishes, it will block forever. I'd use `unbounded()` instead.

Comment: Good point about the request triggering a new request causing a deadlock. For now I'm just trying to get the core idea of a backpressure-pipeline of requests. I will take note of this as a future problem.

Comment: @Stefan @Shepmaster the generate its own buffer came from this bit of documentation: ` The channel capacity is equal to buffer + num-senders. In other words, each sender gets a guaranteed slot in the channel capacity, and on top of that there are buffer`.

Comment: @xrl can you [edit] your question to explain why using `Stream::buffered` doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell your problem with [`channel`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.18/futures/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html) is not that a single clone of the [`Sender`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.18/futures/sync/mpsc/struct.Sender.html) increase the capacity by one, it is that you clone the `Sender` for every item you're trying to send.

The error you're seeing without `clone` comes from your incorrect usage of the `Sink::send` interface.  With `clone` you actually should see the warning:

```
warning: unused `futures::sink::Send` which must be used: futures do nothing unless polled
```

That is: your current code doesn't actually ever send anything!

In order to apply backpressure you need to chain those `send` calls; each one should wait until the previous one finished (and you need to wait for the last one too!); on success you'll get the `Sender` back.  The best way to do this is to generate a `Stream` from your iterator by using [`iter_ok`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.18/futures/stream/fn.iter_ok.html) and to pass it to [`send_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.18/futures/sink/trait.Sink.html#method.send_all).

Now you got one future `SendAll` that you need to "drive".  If you ignore the result and panic on error (`.then(|r| { r.unwrap(); Ok::<(), ()>(()) })`) you could spawn it as a separate task, but maybe you want to integrate it into your main application (i.e. return it in a `Box`).

```rust
// this returns a `Box<Future<Item = (), Error = ()>>`. you may
// want to use a different error type
Box::new(tx.send_all(iter_ok(data)).map(|_| ()).map_err(|_| ()))
```

### `RusotoFuture::sync` and `Future::wait`

Don't use [`Future::wait`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.18/futures/future/trait.Future.html#method.wait): it is already deprecated in a branch, and it usually won't do what you actually are looking for.  I doubt `RusotoFuture` is aware of the problems, so I recommend avoiding `RusotoFuture::sync`.

### Cloning `Sender` increases channel capacity

As you correctly stated cloning `Sender` increases the capacity by one.

This seems to be done to improve performance: A `Sender` starts in the unblocked ("unparked") state; if a `Sender` isn't blocked it can send an item without blocking.  But if the number of items in the queue hits the configured limit when a `Sender` sends an item, the `Sender` becomes blocked ("parked").  (Removing items from the queue will unblock the `Sender` at a certain time.)

This means that after the inner queue hits the limit each `Sender` still can send one item, which leads to the documented effect of increased capacity, but only if actually all the `Sender`s are sending items - unused `Sender`s don't increase the observed capacity.

The performance boost comes from the fact that as long as you don't hit the limit it doesn't need to park and notify tasks (which is quite heavy).

The private documentation at the top of the [`mpsc`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.18/src/futures/sync/mpsc/mod.rs.html#30) module describes more of the details.